# Is reaching the end of a C array legal from the standard view point?

Tags: arrays, c, undefined-behavior

Today, I encountered a piece of C code that looked pretty much like this:

```
void my_func(unsigned int *);

int main() {
  unsigned int a[8];
  // init_a(a); => a is properly initialized 
  my_func(a);

}

void my_func(unsigned int * a) {
    unsigned int * array_begin = a;

    a += 8; // HERE
    while (a-- > array_begin) {
        unsigned int tmp = *a;
        *a = (tmp >> 1);
         // other stuff
    }

}
```

From my understanding, the line `a += 8` brings the pointer right after the end of the array. Then, in the loop condition, the pointer is decremented from this "past array address", dereferenced in the loop body. No problem, because at this point the pointer is back inside the array.

The code compiled and ran without any problems, unit tests were successful.

Still, my question is : is it legal C to move the pointer after the array, and then decrement it to be back inside the allocated object, or is this an undefined behavior ?

Comment: You can set a pointer to anything you want at any time. You can only *dereference it* within allowed bounds.

Comment: @tadman But pointer arithmetic can produce UB if you go too far. 1 past the end is allowed, though.

Comment: _C11 6.5.6_ quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22343583/898348) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Open the text of the standard. Search for the phrase "one past".